# How can I use queryBuilders.wrapperQuery base64 encoded string

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a json string to build a query, and I need to convert this to QueryBuilder. (ES Ver. 6.3.0)

I found that I can use wrapperQuery method, so I wrote this code:

```
String str = cond.getFilter().toString();
QueryBuilder filter = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(str));
```

And these are result of variables in debug mode:

[image]

This method is working right, as the decription in the Docs(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wrapper-query.html)

The problem is, that this query just not working.

[image]

What is wrong and what should I do?

Any comments would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON format seems to be wrong. Since your ASSET_IP is not a number, it must be string in JSON representation. Hence you need to put it as below in your JSON.

```
{ "ASSET_IP" : "xx.xxx.xxx.xx" }
```

Update your JSON with the above and try again.

Comment: Thanks, cannot believe I missed this. I appreciated it so much !